# Is it possible to Display validation errors when page loads in MVC - 4 (with model validations)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to trigger validation error message on page load based on model validations for example.

```
    [Display(Name = "Quantity")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Quantity")]
    [Range(1, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Please enter Qty between the range of 1 to 1000")]
    [RegularExpression("^([0-9])*$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid Qty")]
    public int? QTY { get; set; }
```

If saved value for Qty is 0(zero) in database and I want to fetch it & display on screen which is invalid as per model validation.
So is it possible to trigger that message without any value checks in controller.

Comment: You can switch on client side validation.

Comment: Add a `ModelState` error in the GET method (but why do you have invalid values in your database?)

Comment: I have some tables in database which are used to store values read from excel sheet. It is possible that it contains some invalid data so I have to store it some where after that user have right to correct that data and import it to the system. That is why I have invalid data and I need to display to user that this data is invalid on page load.

Comment: Then use [TryValidateModel()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryvalidatemodel(v=vs.118).aspx) in the GET method

Answer (score 0):

Information given is bit scarce but I'll try.

If you're using [jQuery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) on your client, and you which to show error error messages of the said library. you can try to use something like:

```
$("#myform").validate();
```

If however you which to show the automatic ajax error message block. I recommend going with what [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) proposed in comment.

If you wish for more specific response try to specify all the tools and libraries you have in use regarding validation. Or even simply showing your display solution for form would give ques to what libraries and tools you use.

PS. Try studying the client side solution on showing the wanted error message. If you learn what triggers the message. You should be be able to trigger the same event at ease using an script language etc.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks I will give try. :)

Comment: I have tried your solution but its not working.
ModelState will work but I have to check all the values for properties to add related errors. It is not best solution but I have to use it as there is no other possible solution. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Still unsure about your solution to displaying error messages on client side. I'm sure there is a clean way to do it. For example could you figure out what makes the error messages to pop up is it from script library or does this come from controller?  
There are few different ways to use validation attributes.

Comment: In my case it comes from controller.

Comment: In that case try calling ModelState in your get method just before you open the view: var x = ModelState.IsValid; return View(myList);

Comment: var x is not important its important that you call ModelState. Anyhoo let me know if that triggers your validiation message. Try making it look similar to the way you have your IsValid check on post method.

Comment: I already used 'ModelState.AddError'  & 'ModelState.IsValid'. And its working fine but I was more concern about is there any other way to show on load error on page load based on the Model Validations where I don't need to check for the property value.